# Problems uploading file to MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to upload a file to a remote MongoDB from a local C# Console Application using the official C# driver. The code I'm running is very straight forward, so I don't understand the meaning of the Exception that pops up every time I run it and what to do about it.

```
new MongoClient(ConnectionString)
    .GetServer()
    .GetDatabase("db")
    .GridFS
    .Upload(fileStream, "fileName.ext");
```

Always results in the Exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll

Additional information: The thread is in a RequestStart and the current server instance is not a match for the supplied read preference.